HeadlessException in Github Actions
I have a Selenium testsuite, which I try to execute with use of Github Actions. I initialize chromedriver with these arguments:
case "chrome-headless":
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);

mvn install -DbrowserType=chrome-headless is used to execute tests. It works locally also in headless mode, but fails in case of workflow execution. Error message:

java.awt.HeadlessException:  No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this
program performed an operation which requires it.


Two additional settings may solve your issue
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
Install X virtual frame builder and setup virtual display. This will simulate GUI for tests that still require some form of it even in headless mode:
- name: Install Xvfb
  run: sudo apt-get install -y xvfb dbus-x11

- name: Run Xvfb
  run: |
    Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1920x1080x24 &
    sudo service dbus start

- name: Set virtual display
  run: echo "DISPLAY=:99" >> $GITHUB_ENV

- name: Run Maven Tests
  run: |
    export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
    mvn install -DbrowserType=chrome-headless


I added these steps, but another error appeared:
(java:2846): dbind-WARNING **: 11:41:20.172: AT-SPI: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

I added env var to Disable AT-SPI accessibility warnings. I also added optional code to install and start dbus
